# How can I save a file that is 1 row N number of data points, as a file that is 1 column N number of data points?

Tags: python, text-files

Mock data

```
0.088888888888888892,0.044444444444444439,0.0,-0.044444444444444446,-0.088888888888888878,-0.13333333333333333,-0.18888888888888888,-0.24444444444444444,-0.28888888888888886,-0.34444444444444444,-0.39999999999999997,-0.45555555555555555,-0.51111111111111107,-0.56666666666666665,-0.62222222222222212,-0.6777777777777777,-0.72222222222222221,-0.77777777777777768,-0.82222222222222219,-0.87777777777777777,-0.92222222222222228,-0.97777777777777775,-1.0222222222222221,-1.0777777777777777,-1.1222222222222222,-1.1777777777777776,-1.2222222222222221,-1.2777777777777779,-1.3222222222222222,-1.3777777777777778,-1.4222222222222223,-1.4777777777777776,-1.5222222222222221,-1.5777777777777777,-1.622222222222222,-1.6777777777777776,-1.7222222222222221,-1.7777777777777777,-1.822222222222222,-1.8777777777777778,-1.9222222222222221,-1.9777777777777776,-2.0222222222222221,-2.0777777777777775
```

all on the same row and I want it saved in a text file as

```
0.088888888888888892
0.044444444444444439
0.0
-0.044444444444444446
-0.088888888888888878
-0.13333333333333333
```

ECT(no spaces between, wasn't sure how to format that on here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
file("mockdata.txt", "r").read().replace(",", "\n")
```

Comment: I did this. it just gives me all the values with \n in between instead of an actual line.

Answer (score 1):

```
tr , \\n < input-file > output-file
```

Answer (score -1):

Open in a half-decent editor and search-and-replace the commas for \n newlines, perhaps?  You would need an editor that supports regular expressions.

Or perhaps a SED script?